# On windows cmd, how can I get a list of running tasks with full pathname?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, windows-command-prompt

I know that the TaskList command show the currently running tasks but it does not show the full pathname.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Process Viewer for Windows has a command-line PV.EXE that will show full paths when used with the -v option

http://www.teamcti.com/pview/prcview.htm

```
firefox.exe         1016 Normal   C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
taskmgr.exe         1872 High     C:\Windows\system32\taskmgr.exe
wuauclt.exe         3796 Normal   C:\Windows\system32\wuauclt.exe
explorer.exe        2196 Normal   C:\Windows\explorer.exe
cmd.exe             4972 Normal   C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
```

Answer (score 2):

[Powershell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/download.mspx) can do this:

```
get-process | get-item -erroraction silentlycontinue | format-table name, directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Try tasklist /v

Comment: Even with verbose settings, it still wont get the location for all.

Answer (score 0):

TLIST used to do that, but it was replaced. 
[Read This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc267860.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

Here is an app that will do it, but it's not a command window app.

http://www.techbuzz.in/how-can-i-find-exe-location-of-processes-in-windows-xp-task-manager.php